# Converting an Excel Range to a Table

Tags: angular, typescript, office-js

I'm trying to use Office.js API to build an Angular Excel add-in, but I'm having a problem converting an Excel.Range to an Excel.Table.

I have a code like the example below binded to a button click, but although I manage to get the documentLines in the Excel Sheet, no table is created.

```
getExampleTable() {

    const documentLinesHeader = [["Period 1", "Period 2", "Period 3"]];

    const documentLines = [
        ["Line 1.1", "Line 1.2", "Line 1.3"],
        ["Line 2.1", "Line 2.2", "Line 2.3"],
        ["Line 3.1", "Line 3.2", "Line 3.3"],
    ];

    const documentLinesCount = documentLines.length;
    const columnCount = documentLines[0].length;

    Excel.run(async (ctx) => {        

        let sheet = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();

        let cell = sheet.getCell(0,0);

        let tableRange = cell.getResizedRange(documentLinesCount - 1, columnCount - 1);

        tableRange.load("address");

        await ctx.sync();

        console.log("Table Range is:", tableRange.address);
        // Outputs Table Range is: Sheet1!A1:C3

        tableRange.values = documentLines;

        let exampleTable = sheet.tables.add(tableRange, true);
        exampleTable.getHeaderRowRange().values = documentLinesHeader;
        exampleTable.name = "ExampleTable";

        return await ctx.sync();
    })
    .catch(this.errorHandler);
}
```

If I look at the console, I have the error:

```
Debug info: {"code":"InvalidArgument","message":"The argument is invalid or 
missing or has an incorrect format.","errorLocation":"TableCollection.add"}
```

My Office Version is:
    16.0.4639.1000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I found that there is some kind of problem with my version of Office that makes it impossible to "add" a Range object to the TableCollection. Although the documentation clearly states that the parameter can be "A Range object, or a string address or name of the range representing the data source."

The workaround to this problem, is to load the address of the Range, and pass that instead to the add method. Using my snippet above, you have to load the address, and then, instead of passing the Range object, pass the range address, like this:

```
let exampleTable = sheet.tables.add(tableRange.address, true);
```

Comment: Glad to hear that you figured it out and thanks for sharing this info.  I've logged an issue in the **office-js** repo (https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/52) to report this to the product team.

Comment: Please see my comment on https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/52#issuecomment-359530509.  Even though the method is a `1.1` one, the ability to pass a `Range` object is part of `1.3`.  The IntelliSense comment notes this, but it looks like our documentation does not.  My apologies, we'll get it fixed.  See the comment on GitHub for more details.

Comment: Thanks, @Michael Zlatkovsky. The docs have been updated with this info: https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/excel/tablecollection.

Answer (score 2):

I'm unable to reproduce the issue that you've described. According to the docs, `TableCollection.add` [is part of requirement set 1.1](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/excel/tablecollection) and [your version of Office does support that requirement set](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/requirement-sets/excel-api-requirement-sets).

The following function (a somewhat streamlined/simplified version of your function) successfully populates a range with data and then creates a table from that range.

```
async function getExampleTable_2() {
    await Excel.run(async (context) => {

        const values = [
            ["Period 1", "Period 2", "Period 3"],
            ["Line 1.1", "Line 1.2", "Line 1.3"],
            ["Line 2.1", "Line 2.2", "Line 2.3"],
            ["Line 3.1", "Line 3.2", "Line 3.3"]
        ];

        // Get active sheet.
        let sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();

        // Get Range object that encompasses table data.
        let tableRange = sheet.getCell(0, 0).getResizedRange(values.length - 1, values[0].length - 1);

        // Write values to the range.
        tableRange.values = values;

        // Create a table from the range.
        let exampleTable = sheet.tables.add(tableRange, true);

        exampleTable.name = "ExpensesTable";

        await context.sync();
    }).catch(errorHandler);
}
```

You can try this snippet yourself by using Script Lab (https://aka.ms/getscriptlab). Simply install the Script Lab add-in (free), then choose "Import" in the navigation menu, and use the following Gist URL: https://gist.github.com/kbrandl/fcb894084eb764098156965aeefb5bf2.

Comment: Just tried your suggestion, and both buttons fail with the same error... Could it be some Edge version issue? (I believe the add-ins use the Edge engine, correct?)

Comment: Add-ins on the Desktop currently use Internet Explorer 11 (or lower if the computer doesn't have IE 11). In Office Online, Add-ins simply run in an iFrame.  Did you try my running my snippet in Script Lab or did you copy/paste the function into your Angular app?

Comment: I've run the script lab with your gist. So, I tried the online versions, both on IE11 and Edge, and both worked. This must be some kind of problem with my desktop Office version...

Comment: I found the problem (some kind of bug in office maybe?). Will answer bellow. Thank you for help @Kim Brand.